# How to make the id auto increasing by 2 in the Model of Django?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

Since the auto_increment setting in the MySQL is for the global, which cannot be set to a specific table?

I'm considering if it's possible to make the id auto increasing by 2 in the Model of Django?

models.py

```
class Video(models.Model):
    name = model.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    upload_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

What should I do? Thanks for ur help.

Comment: You could insert a "fake" video object for every real object, and then remove it. But even then you have no guarantees, since different databases can have specific sequences to assign ids. Why do you want to do that? Why not simply mulitplying the `id` with 2 in case you communicate it to the outside world?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it my overriding **`save()`** method of your model as

```
from django.db.models import Max, F


class Video(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    upload_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            max = Video.objects.aggregate(max=Max(F('id')))['max']
            self.id = max + 2 if max else 1 # if the DB is empty
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

the correct way is to change your mysql server settings
check this out: [auto_increment_increment](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment)

Comment: it will affect all tables in the database, but I only wanna affect the Video table...

Answer (score 0):

Possible Solutions:

Assume I have a Model of Customer.

```
Customer.objects.order_by('primay_key_id ').last().primay_key_id + 2)

primay_key_id = models.IntegerField(default=(Customer.objects.order_by('primay_key_id ').last().primay_key_id + 2),primary_key=True)
```

or

```
from django.db import transaction
#Uncomment Lines for Django version less than 2.0
def save(self): 
      "Get last value of Code and Number from database, and increment before save"
      #with transaction.atomic():
        #top = Customer.objects.select_for_update(nowait=True).order_by('-customer_customerid')[0] #Ensures Lock on Database
      top = Customer.objects.order_by('-id')[0]
      self.id = top.id + 1
      super(Customer, self).save()
```

The Above Code would not have a Concurrency Issue for Django 2.0 as:

*As of Django 2.0, related rows are locked by default (not sure what the behaviour was before) and the rows to lock can be specified in the same style as select_related using the of parameter!
For Lower Versions, you need to be atomic!*

or

```
from django.db import transaction
def increment():
  with transaction.atomic():        
    ids = Customer.objects.all()
    length = len(ids)-1
    if(length<=0): #Changed to Handle empty Entries
     return 1
    else:
     id = ids[length].customer_customerid
     return id+2
```

or

```
from django.db import transaction
def increment():
  with transaction.atomic():        
    return Customer.objects.select_for_update(nowait=True).order_by('-customer_customerid')[0] #Ensures Atomic Approach!
```

and set primary key in model to Integer Field and on every new entry `primary_key_field=increment()` Like

and then in your Models.py
set the Primary_Key to:

```
import increment()
primay_key_id = models.IntegerField(default=increment(),primary_key=True)
```

Comment: Apprieciate, I added a New line of Code to Handle if Table in Empty. Kindly Follow that Change :)

Comment: Don't do this. There are at least three major issues: 1) it's subject to race conditions; 2) it doesn't take account of any deleted items; 3) you call the function in the default attribute instead of passing the callable, so the value will always be the same.

Comment: Well, It is a Solution that works Quite well for a Single Table with that Thing and I am using it in my own Django Rest API and it did worked Quite well, You can also Override the Save Method which would eliminate most of the Stuff!